# Corners with border - is there any possibility?

Tags: html, css

Let assume that I have image with `border: 1 px solid black` because i want it to have border. But for more i want rounded corners so i give  `border-radius: 10px`. But this now looks bad because corners don't have border. Is there possibility in html and css to do something which give borders to corners or answer is maybe somewhere in (for example) in jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sure just put the border on too.. and where there's a background color you can use an image, however IE support will be non-existant, but you might try [CSSPie](http://css3pie.com/) for enhancement for it. I think also some browsers do have a problem clipping on image to the round corners but am not too sure on overall support or fixes, perhaps putting the border on a parent div then rounding the image inside it might give a neat effect?

#### [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/r8GDv/)

```
div, img {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #0f0;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>rounded with border</div>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100/" alt="">
```

---

**Update:** Webkit browsers do have problems with this if it's actually an image that  needs rounding with borders, here's one workaround that seems to help:

### [New Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/VZP6N/)

(view with webkit to see difference between second and third images)

HTML:

```
<div class="ri"><img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100/" alt=""></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
   margin: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 40px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}

.ri {
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}

.ri img {
   display: block;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

the [background-clip](http://www.webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/) is supposed to help the background clip to the padding-box, which should in theory stop a `background-image or color` from extending into the border, but in itself it doesn't appear to work very well, so I nested the image and rounded both it and the parent div and then put the border onto the parent div, Webkit was happy ;)

Comment: no the image has them as well, but webkit still needs a little help, it extends the image into the "border-box" - I will update with the img nested in div scenario

Answer (score 1):

You might try this [curved-corner project](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/) on Google Code that purports to allow the `border-radius` CSS property to work cross-browser.

Comment: Looks good. I need add this to css:
.curved {

 -moz-border-radius:10px;

 -webkit-border-radius:10px;

 behavior:url(border-radius.htc);

}
But .htc files is new for me. Could You tell me what should I do with this file. How to attach it to my page?

Comment: Download the .htc file from the Google project page, put it somewhere in your website files, and reference it with the `behavior: url(border-radius.htc);` rule in the `.curved` area of your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you can write with css3 & for IE you can download [piecss3](http://css3pie.com/) js.

**Example**

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:2px solid yellow;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

check this
 http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/KDBGV/

Comment: Now there are square image with rounded corners. Is there possibility in piecss3 to give rounded corners to picture and then give rounded border?

Answer (score 1):

The other ways is:

CSS:

```
.container {
  background:gray; 
  color:#fff; 
  margin:0 15px;
}
.rtop, .rbottom {
  display:block;
  background:#fff;
}
.crvtop *, .crvbottom {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:gray;
}
.r1{margin: 0 5px}
.r2{margin: 0 3px}
.r3{margin: 0 2px}
.r4{margin: 0 1px; height: 2px}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <b class="crvtop">
       <b class="r1"></b>
       <b class="r2"></b>
       <b class="r3"></b>
       <b class="r4"></b>
   </b>
   Place the content here
   <b class="crvbottom">
       <b class="r4"></b>
       <b class="r3"></b>
       <b class="r2"></b>
       <b class="r1"></b>
   </b>
</div>
```

This is going to work in all the browsers.

Cheers and Enjoy :)

Comment: seems some error while posting
visit the site http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa072406.htm
demo available at http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/bl_cssroundedcorners.htm

Comment: All this classes are classes of what?

Comment: Now something is wrong. This code is not working. Hmm.. Shouldn't somwhere in in html be .rtop class and .rbottom class?

Answer (score 0):

Well Cris,
The classes are for the spanned elements to create a curvy edges. Simply modify

```
.rtop, .rbottom {
  display:block;
  background:#fff;
}

.crvtop *, .crvbottom {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:gray;
}
```

with

```
.crvtop, .crvbottom {
  display:block;
  background:#fff;
}

.crvtop *, .crvbottom * {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:gray;
}
```

and it will work

Hope that helps..

Comment: It gives me square image on width gray rectangle.